# Possible bug in inline link processing for comments

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, markdown, hyperlinks

I've just noticed that there appears to be a bug when trying to write an inline link in a comment using markdown.  If the URL contains a `http://` in the path component of the URI, things go wonky.

For example, I tried to include a link to a page archived on archive.org:

```
 Read the [archived version on archive.org](http://web.archive.org/web/20071102233627/http://xooglers.blogspot.com/2005/12/lets-get-real-database.html)
```

This rendered as:

> Read the [xooglers.blogspot.com/2005/12/…](http://web.archive.org/web/20071102233627/%3Ca%20href=)" rel="nofollow">archived version on archive.org

In this specific case, you *can* manually edit the URL and drop the `http://` from the path and archive.org still works, but that feels like a hacky fix.

Comment: I know that the team has stated that this is **`[by-design]`**.  It is too much work to parse links with the `http:` in them.  Too much work for too little gain.

Comment: Interesting.  When you simply paste in the URL, it is parsed and linked correctly: http://web.archive.org/web/20071102233627/http://xooglers.blogspot.com/2005/12/lets-get-real-database.html  AFAIK, having `http:` in a URL's path isn't technically invalid, is it?

Comment: @josh, no, it is not technically invalid I don't think

Comment: *(Note to self: A comment with 4 negatives is really effing hard to understand.)*

Comment: @Justin: [ *We don't need no education* ](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/The_IT_Crowd#The_Red_Door_.5B1.4.5D "Yes, you do. You just used a double negative")

Comment: Fixed, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69879/comment-nofollow-exploit

Answer (score 1):

You must escape the illegal characters in the URL.

Comment: So if I enter `%3A` for `:`, things should be groovy?  Let's [test](http://web.archive.org/web/20071102233627/http%3A//xooglers.blogspot.com/2005/12/lets-get-real-database.html).  That's a bit of an onerous requirement to impose on users, no?  Especially considering that the major browsers display the colon unencoded - in fact, Chrome actually *converts `%3A` back to `:`* in the address bar.  Even if the browsers aren't functioning *strictly* to spec (`:` is a reserved character), users should still be able to just copy-and-paste URLs from their address bar.